# Is there an explicit bound on the number of tetrahedra needed to triangulate a hyperbolic 3-manifold of volume V?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

Is there an explicit bound on the number of tetrahedra needed to triangulate a hyperbolic 3-manifold of volume $V$?  Or more generally a hyperbolic $n$-manifold of volume $V$?

Comment: There can't be, as there's only finitely many manifolds triangulable with $n$ tetrahedra, and there's infinitely many hyperbolic manifolds of volume $\leq V$ provided $V$ is the volume of, say, the figure-8 knot complement -- there's infinitely many hyperbolic manifolds you get by filling in the boundary torus, and the volume is less than whatever the figure-8 complement volume is.  

Comment: The Wikipedia page with the relevant theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_Dehn_surgery

Comment: Er, I suppose such a bound in principal exists it just can't be a "nice" bound.  There's only finitely many hyperbolic manifolds of a given volume, so the bound is the max of the minimal number of tetrahedra needed to triangulate those manifolds.  That's not an *informative* bound.  The argument above basically says bound, as a function of $V$ is awfully complicated and certainly not an increasing function in $V$ 

Comment: So the problem is that any such bound function $f(V)$ would "know" the volumes of all the cusped hyperbolic $3$-manifolds as that's where it would blow up.  But this is the kind of information that (at present) is not readily available.  Basic questions like "is this real number $x$ the volume of a hyperbolic $3$-manifold?" are difficult to answer. 

Comment: As far as I know, no one has computed an explicit constant (as pointed out, in dimension 3, one could only hope for a triangulation of the thick part). Breslin has some results:
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2507575

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A couple of things are true:
1.  If you have any Riemannian manifold of bounded infinitesimal geometry (curvature pinched above and below), its thick part, where the injectivity radius $> \epsilon$, can be triangulated with a number of simplices bounded by a constant times volume, where the constant depends on the curvature bounds and the dimension.  I don't personally know the constant even for hyperbolic 3-manifolds,  but I think there are people who can produce explicit bounds. This is basically a consequence of the compactness of the set of manifolds of bounded infinitesimal geometry and injectivity radius bounded below, together with the fact that all smooth manifolds admit a smooth triangulation, and that any smooth triangulation of a closed subset can be extended.

1. For hyperbolic 3-manifolds, if you allow "spun triangulations" where some tetrahedra are allowed to have missing vertices that spiral infinitely around a short closed geodesic, then there is a similar bound, the number is less than some constant times volume.  To do it:  first triangulate the thick part leaving a boundary torus, then make cones on the boundary triangles that spiral around a short geodesic.

The answers are the same whether you're asking for a geodesic triangulation of a hyperbolic manifold, or any smooth triangulation.