# Measuring the complexity of a knot by minimum number of simplices to tile the complement

Tags: knot-theory, gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

> This is essentially a duplicate of: [Lower bound on number of tetrahedra needed to triangulate a knot complement](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46149/)

Suppose a knot $K\subseteq\mathbb S^3$ is such that the complement $\mathbb S^3\setminus K$ has an ideal triangulation with $n$ simplices.  What is the best bound on the crossing number $\operatorname{cr}(K)$ in terms of $n$? [perhaps we want to restrict to hyperbolic knots]

I'm half expecting that there is no such bound (probably because of twisting around a fixed unknot in the complement of $K$).  In such a case, I'd like to ask for the following weaker bound in the same spirit, which I strongly suspect exists (though I'm not sure what it should be):

Suppose a knot $K\subseteq\mathbb S^3$ is such that the complement $\mathbb S^3\setminus K$ has an ideal triangulation with $n$ simplices.  This of course gives a triangulation of the boundary torus $\partial N_\epsilon(K)$, and I define $A(\text{an isotopy class of simple closed curve in }\partial N_\epsilon(K))$ to be the minimum number of geometric intersections between the curve and the $1$-simplices in the triangulation of $\partial N_\epsilon(K)$.  What is the best bound on $\operatorname{cr}(K)+A(m)$ (where $m$ is the meridian of $K$) in terms of $n$?

Comment: Shouldn't there be finitely many arrangements of $n$ simplices, therefore finitely many complements, therefore finitely many knots, therefore a bound on the crossing number?

Comment: @ Will: Yes, by the knot complement problem. 

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of this question:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46149/lower-bound-on-number-of-tetrahedra-needed-to-triangulate-a-knot-complement/46204#46204

Translating between ideal triangulations and triangulations with boundary is a linear procedure. 